# How to apply click event on html tree node using power shell?

Tags: html, powershell, scripting

I am trying to automate one repeating activity by using power shell. Actually , the script should login to the page and expand tree nodes which are available under div tags.
[Tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03IeM.png)

[DOM Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crfSk.png)
Here is my code snippet. Due to privacy reasons I have not provided sample URL.

```
$url = "url of my application"
$username="userName"
$password="ChangeMe"

$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url);


while ($ie.Busy -eq $true)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;
}

$ie.Document.getElementById("IDToken1").value = $username
$ie.Document.getElementByID("IDToken2").value=$password
$ie.Document.getElementById("Login.Submit").Click();



Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;
}


$Option = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('span12') | Where-Object  {$_.innerText -eq 'FBN'} 

$Option.Click();

exit
```

After execution i could able to successfully login to web page but failing to apply click/ expand the tree node and tried many approaches by going through different suggestions, but no lunk with below error..

"**You cannot call a method on a null valued expression"**

Please suggest any other alternative ways to move further.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it a little, I am not sure if it can be done.

A lot of the html and js code is generated after the page is loaded. If you look at the actual html code (view source).

Btw, I am also getting the same error even searching for ElementByID of the page.